Does Russia plan to have any involvement with the rescue of stranded astronauts in the ISS?
I was just curious if Russia has been involved with the rescue planning in any way? I thought I read that they had transported astronauts to and from the ISS in the past. Do they no longer make the rockets or perhaps are they no longer involved?
I tried to read it in the news but seem to be having problems finding the information. It could just be me. I thought someone might know.

I am confident that the Russians will be made aware of the situation, but I doubt very much if they would be asked or required to do anything. The most likely scenario is that the next Crewed Dragon flight will be fitted with 2 extra seats (Dragon can accommodate up to 7). Then either some people have to come home early or some people have to spend longer on the ISS.

@Slarty Thank you. I had not found much comment on this angle in the press and appreciate your answer,

" I thought I read that they had transported astronauts to and from the ISS in the past. Do they no longer make the rockets or perhaps are they no longer involved?" - they are still involved (usually in the ROS section though), and they do still make rockets for sending both people and cargo, some are docked right now (1 people carrier and two cargo ships). Involvement is less a technical issue and probably more of a political one. As Slarty said, it is unlikely they will be asked to do anything.

Russia and the U.S. continue to carry each other’s astronauts to space as a way to make sure that there is always someone from each country onboard the U.S. and Russian segments of the International Space Station. Most recently Russian cosmonaut Alexander Grebenkin rode on the SpaceX Dragon Crew 8 capsule. And NASA astronaut Loral O'Hara rode on the Russian Soyuz MS-24 capsule. Quite remarkable when you think about it considering the current state of relations between the U.S. and Russia.

@Slarty the current plan is to launch Dragon with 2 astronauts and have the marooned folks fill in for the original other two - including staying on the ISS till next year(!).

@Organic Marble interesting, and yes that works just as well I suppose.

They are not "stranded" nor in need of "rescue". There are an enormous number of sources that go into the situation in detail.

Disregarding the political and PR aspects, the correct way to travel in a Soyuz capsule is inside a Sokhol space suit to provide air and cooling, and seated in a custom seat liner (also).
The current Starliner crew have neither of those things currently with them. It is unclear just how dangerous an optimal re-entry would be, but a number of otherwise minor emergencies become likely to be fatal.
This is largely irrelevant since the single Soyuz docked already has three people on the ISS who would like to ride it home. A Soyuz return would involve launching a rescue mission with one crew, two empty seats and presumably some best guesses as to suits, liners and other supporting equipment. The manufacturing pipeline for Soyuz capsules means this mission would most likely take weeks to months to prepare.
At this point in August 2024 this appears unlikely to be required with short term contingency planing focusing on return via overloading the crew-8 Dragon capsule home* and next Dragon up potentially traveling with two empty seats.
*Space X dragon had a design capacity of 7 but currently flies with 4, unlike Soyuz that is tight for 3. Following the coolant leak on Soyuz MS-22 planning and assessment was done that appeared to indicate that rigging for more was possible using equipment available on the ISS.

@GremlinWanger Thank you for the informative answer. Sometimes its difficult for layman like myself to get the additional detail. This was very interesting information.
